# Linear vector fields $\leftrightarrow$ certain differential operators

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $E \to M$ a vector bundle.

I'm reading a text which says:

> Recall that there is a one-to-one correspondence between:
>
> 1. linear vector fields on $E$, and
> 2. linear operators $D : \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E)$ such that there exists a vector field $X$ on $M$ such that
>    $$D(fs) = f D(s) + X(f) s$$
>    for all $f \in C^\infty(M)$ and $s \in \Gamma(E)$.

Unfortunately, I can't recall ever seeing this. I'm not even sure what is a linear vector field (Google hasn't return anything useful).

What is this correspondence? If this is a standard fact, where is it explained (textbook/lecture notes/paper)?

Comment: What do you mean by a linear vector field on $E$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese This is part of the question...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese My guess is a vector field $Y$ which is homogeneous of degree $0$, i.e. $dm_t(Y_e) = Y_{te}$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $e \in E$, where $m_t$ is scalar multiplication by $t$. The reason is that if $(x^1, \ldots, x^n)$ are coordinates on $M$ and $(s_1, \ldots, s_k)$ is a local frame of $E$, then $Y = f^i(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + g^i_j(x) y^j \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$, where $(x^1, \ldots, x^n, y^1, \ldots, y^k)$ are the corresponding coordinates on $E$.

Comment: The vector field $X$ on $M$ is then presumably $X = f^i(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.

Comment: (2) seems to be just a connection in $E$ with a specific (fixed) vector field plugged into it (I mean, into the corresponding covariant derivative); so you can uniquely recover $X$ from $D$ but not the connection itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using google (linear vector field on vecot bundle), I found the following reasonable definition for a linear vector field $\hat X$  on a vector bundle $E\to M:$ it is a vector field $\hat X\in\mathcal X(E)$ which is a vector bundle morphism $\hat X\colon E\to TE$ along a map $X\colon M\to TM$ given by a vector field on $M.$

The one-to-one correspondence is given as follows:

$1\Rightarrow2:$ if you have a linear vector field $\hat X$ on $E$, and a section $s\colon \Gamma(M,E)$ consider the difference $$\hat D_ps:=T_p s(X)-\hat X_{s(p)}\in T_{s(p)}E,$$ where $T$ denotes the differential of the smooth map $s\colon M\to E$. It can be checked using the definition that $\hat D_ps$ is in the vertical tangent  bundle $\mathcal V$, i.e., in the kernel of the differential of the projection $\pi\colon E\to M.$ On the other handd, there is a canonical isomorphism $$\pi^*E=\mathcal V\to E.$$ Then, for any section $s\colon M\to E$ we obtain $$s^*\pi^*\mathcal V=E.$$  Using this observation, we can identify the map $$p\in M\mapsto   \hat D_ps\in \mathcal V_{s(p)}$$ with a section $Ds\in\Gamma(M,E).$$

$2\Rightarrow1:$ given a first order differential operator $D$ the prescribed properties, one can define the vector field $\hat X$ by reversing the above process.

Unfortunately, I do not know a detailed reference for the above, but it is closely related to Ehresmann-type treatmeant of linear connections (by replacing directional derivatives with the differential respectively $D$ with a linear connection $\nabla$ on $E$).